# How do I include Enumerable in a project using sorbet?

Tags: ruby, sorbet

If I define an enumerable class like

```rb
# typed: strict

class MyEnumerable
  extend T::Generic
  extend T::Sig
  include Enumerable

  Elem = type_member

  sig {override.params(blk: T.proc.params(arg: Elem).returns(BasicObject)).returns(NilClass)}
  def each(&blk)
  end
end
```

This type checks with `srb tc` just fine, but if I try to run `srb rbi update`, I get an error. Checking the `reflection.json.err`

```
reflection.rbi:15619: Type variable `Elem` needs to be declared as `= type_member(SOMETHING)` https://srb.help/5018
       15619 |  Elem = ::T.let(nil, ::T.untyped)
                ^^^^
```

Changing the `Elem` declaration to (i.e. how it is defined [in the `Enumerable` rbi](https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/blob/bdbfd4878ab168469e4a32886337f45aeec00b11/rbi/core/enumerable.rbi#L11))

```rb
    Elem = type_member(:out)
```

now `srb tc` gives me the error

```
Classes can only have invariant type members https://srb.help/5016
     9 |    Elem = type_member(:out)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Errors: 1
```

changing the `Elem` declaration to

```rb
    Elem = type_member(:invariant)
```

now `srb tc` gives me the error

```
Invalid variance kind, only :out and :in are supported https://srb.help/4011
     9 |    Elem = type_member(:invariant)
                               ^^^^^^^^^^
Errors: 1
```

How can I implement an `Enumerable` class in a project using sorbet such that it both type checks and doesn't error when running `srb rbi update`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug in Sorbet. I don't know of a workaround. Please file an issue at https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet. Unfortunately we have limited resources and so will have to make a decision about how to prioritize this.

Comment: Done. For reference: https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/issues/2606